# Reading from a dynamic list on screen and some options are getting skipped when catch is executed?

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, telerik, selenium-chromedriver

I am using a for loop to cycle through a dynamic list and some of the options are getting skipped when I have to execute a Catch inside it.

```
for (int index = 0; index < exports.Rows.Count; index++)
        {
            try
            {
                var reportListBox = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("rlbList"));
                IWebElement reportItem = reportListBox.FindElement(By.CssSelector($"#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_lstReports_i{index}"));
                reportItem.Click();
                exportBTNClick();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // If Error Message appears then Click ok 
                driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='rwInnerSpan'][contains(text(),'OK')]")).Click();
                driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='rwInnerSpan'][contains(text(),'OK')]")).Click();
            }
        }
```

The code shows the For loop and will gather the information from the list, then the purpose of `reportItem.Click();` is to click on the option that is displayed on screen.

The `exportBTNClick();` method will click a button on screen and generate a report. If the report cannot be generated (i.e. no valid data) then it should move to the Catch where it clicks the OK button twice.

What is happening then is that the OK button is being clicked and the next report t be exported is 2 or 3 places ahead of the last selection (i.e. if report 2 fails should go to report 3 but instead is going to report 4 or 5)

Comment: You really shouldn't be using exceptions for flow control.

Comment: yeah changed it now. Didn't know that as I'm still learning, will post the code for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was found that the export method was being called and then the error message for no data was available. As the error message was only appearing for the next item in the sequence then as there was the error message on screen from the last export, it was jumping to the catch portion of the statement.

The new code looks like this:

```
for (int index = 0; index < exports.Rows.Count; index++)
        {
            var reportListBox = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("rlbList"));
            IWebElement reportItem = reportListBox.FindElement(By.CssSelector($"#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_lstReports_i{index}"));

            reportItem.Click();
            exportBTNClick();

            IWebElement modal = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='rwInnerSpan'][contains(text(),'OK')]"));                  
            if (modal.Displayed == true)
            {

                // If Error Message appears then Click ok
                driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='rwInnerSpan'][contains(text(),'OK')]")).Click();

                driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='rwInnerSpan'][contains(text(),'OK')]")).Click();

            }


        }
```